# How to change page url and page content without reload the page?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, url

I want to do that when I clicked on link (for example test.com/page?=test) my tab in the broswer open the link but without reload or refresh the page and change the content to the page content.

How can I start it? I know PHP, but its the first time that I try to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modify the URL without reloading the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page)

Answer (score 0):

[You can use HTML5 History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_pushState()_method)

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    if(event.target.tagName === 'A'){
       event.preventDefault();
       history.replaceState({}, "Page Title", event.target.href);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, i doubt there is any easy way for this.
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp
This might help.